# suggested edits counter graphic

Tags: feature-request, design, suggested-edits

For 10k users and mods, whenever the queue of suggested edits is non-empty, the following sign pops up in the bar at the top:

[image: suggested edits indicator]

That counter looks out-of-place compared with the rest of the design. For example, the featured questions indicator looks like

[image: featured questions indicator]

It would look better if the suggested edits indicator (also the on on `/review`) had the same design as the other indicators.

Comment: It actually looks quite similar to the moderation one (which is sort-of orange on yellow)

Comment: Related: [Change the color of the number of suggested edits](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/5764)